# IndexError: list index out of range,but it does not

Tags: python, list, indexing

```
def change(txt):    
    for i in range(9):
        k=len(txt[i])
        for j in range(k):

            if txt[i][j-1]=='6':
                txt[i].pop(j)
            if '\n' in txt[i]:
                txt[i].remove('\n')
        k=0
change(sd)
```

It shows that:
     if txt[i][j-1]=='6':
    IndexError: list index out of range

txt is a nesting list

i changed to
def change(txt):
    s=len(txt)
    for i in range(s):
        k=len(txt[i])
        print(k)
        for j in range(k):
            if txt[i][j].isdigit:
                if txt[i][j-2].isdigit:
                    del txt[i][j-1]
            if '\n' in txt[i]:
                txt[i].remove('\n')
            if txt[i][j]==',':
                txt[i][j]=='.'
        k=0

same error

Comment: and txt has len 9 for sure.

Comment: and i add 
s=len(txt)
for i in range(s):
still give me the same error

Comment: [[',', ',', ',', ',', ',', '6', ',', ',', ',', '\n'], [',', '5', ',', '9', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', '8', '\n'], ['2', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', '8', ',', ',', ',', '\n'], [',', '4', ',', '5', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', '\n'], [',', ',', '3', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', '\n'], [',', ',', '6', ',', ',', ',', '3', ',', ',', '5', ',', '4', '\n'], [',', ',', ',', '3', ',', '2', ',', '5', ',', ',', ',', '6', '\n'], [',', '5', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', '\n'], [',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', '\n']]
This is txt

Comment: and i want to change '6' to '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'and'9' . how should i do that

Comment: Please don't scribble in comments. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57238578/edit) your question to add details.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `[j - 1]` which points to an index which is out of the list. Change the code from `for j in range(k)` to `for j in range(k-1)`

Comment: It's `j - 1`, not `j + 1`. How would changing range to `k-1` help here?

Comment: ` for j in range(k)` --> ` for j in range(k-1)`

Comment: It doest change
    if txt[i][j]=='6':
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: if the least j-1 is -1 which is still in the list